# FontAwesomeIconView not found in Scene Builder 16.0.0 with openjdk 11.0.10

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fontawesomefx

I can't find the FontAwesomeIconView in Scene Builder 16.0.0.
[These are the only modules imported when I add the fontawesomefx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4UBV.png)

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I'm being silly. So just search repository and search "fontawesome". Choose "de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-9.1.2"