# SceneBuilder-8.5.0 javafx could not open FXML pages

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have an fxml files that I created using SceneBuilder-8.5.0. These files are used in my JavaFx project that I am developing using NetBeans 8. I tried to add fontawesomefx.jar to fxml and all my pages stoped working. When I try to open any page, this SceneBuilder error message appears

```
 java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/genop/OneDrive/Desktop/pi/Just-Another-Pi-Dev/src/shared/gui/register_pageGuest.fxml

    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:98)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:89)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:106)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2540)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:761)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:385)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:672)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.access$100(SceneBuilderApp.java:98)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp$1.invalidated(SceneBuilderApp.java:524)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.UserLibrary.lambda$updateFirstExplorationCompleted$6(UserLibrary.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/genop/OneDrive/Desktop/pi/Just-Another-Pi-Dev/src/shared/gui/register_pageGuest.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2848)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:93)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
    ... 27 more
```

and this is my fxml code for the page i added fontawesomefx icones in after i deleted the icons on the fxml code still not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXRadioButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane fx:id="parentContainer" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="779.0" prefWidth="1383.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="shared.gui.Login_pageController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="rootPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass">
         <stylesheets>
            <URL value="@/shared/gui/Style/controls.css" />
         </stylesheets>
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="anchorPane" fitHeight="780.0" fitWidth="1396.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../resources/bg_image.jpg" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fitHeight="32.0" fitWidth="37.0" layoutX="546.0" layoutY="360.0" opacity="0.74" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               
            </ImageView>
            <Button fx:id="login_button" layoutX="794.0" layoutY="478.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#attempteToLogin" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="127.0" styleClass="button1" stylesheets="@Style/controls.css" text="Login" wrapText="true" />
            <Button fx:id="Register_button" layoutX="1151.0" layoutY="54.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#signUp" onMouseClicked="#registerClicked" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="181.0" styleClass="button1" stylesheets="@Style/controls.css" text="Sign Up" wrapText="true" />
            <JFXTextField fx:id="emailtxt" focusColor="#ffa781" labelFloat="true" layoutX="585.0" layoutY="360.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="332.0" promptText="Email" styleClass="label1" stylesheets="@Style/controls.css" unFocusColor="WHITE" />
            <JFXPasswordField fx:id="passwordtxt" focusColor="#ffa781" labelFloat="true" layoutX="585.0" layoutY="414.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="332.0" promptText="Password" style="-fx-font-size: 19;" styleClass="label1" stylesheets="@Style/controls.css" unFocusColor="WHITE" />
            <JFXRadioButton fx:id="remember_me" layoutX="555.0" layoutY="481.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="156.0" styleClass="raaa" stylesheets="@Style/controls.css" text="Remember me" />
            <ImageView fitHeight="32.0" fitWidth="32.0" layoutX="1337.0" layoutY="14.0" onMouseClicked="#close" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../resources/close.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Label layoutX="990.0" layoutY="63.0" styleClass="label1" stylesheets="@Style/controls.css" text="Not a member ?" />
            <Hyperlink fx:id="fp_hyperlink" layoutX="627.0" layoutY="724.0" onAction="#forgetPassword" styleClass="Fpss" stylesheets="@Style/controls.css" text="Forgot your password?" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: after researching i found that I can't load FXML pages in scene builder without  adding  all the used dependencies in the FXML.

Comment: Even if you got it to work, I think it is in advisable to use such obsolete software. Instead, use [modern equivalents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70985646/load-custom-components-in-scenebuilder-17), including modern jdk, JavaFX (17.0.2+), IDE, scene builder and dependent library versions.

Comment: this is academic project, I have no choose but to use it :/

Comment: If you found a solution, you should [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I can't since I don't have  15 reputation yet